# Primereact's calendar component generates every month after 12th with non-unique key

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I'm using primereact's calendar component. I have a prop

`numberOfMonths={18}`

To give me 18 months/columns. Problem with that is that it generated every additional month after 12 with same children element keys, so I get a bunch of these errors:

```
Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `8`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates.....
```

Is there any way around this so that primereact generates additional months with unique keys? Thanks.

This is how my full component with props looks like:

```
<Calendar value={dates} onChange={(e : CalendarChangeEvent) =>  verticalDateHandler(e.value)}numberOfMonths={18} minDate={today} selectionMode="range" dateFormat="YYYY MMM DD" touchUI inline viewDate={today}/>
```

Tried removing "touchUI", tried removing viewDate prop, tried updatingLocale with extra month names. No dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be fixed in 9.3.1+ with this fix: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/pull/4260

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be just a bug with no solution right now.

reported it on GitHub issues